# How can i extract a woocommercial price from this? using request and BS4 Python

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

[₱81,495.00]

I have been stuck for several days because of this.
I want to extract data of 81,495.00 from BDI.
any suggestion ? Thank you.

do you have a link of other references for the techniques in webscraping?. I would probably appreciate more.

the html is in comment

Comment: ""[<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₱</span>81,495.00</bdi></span></ins>]""

Answer (score 0):

Upon selecting the `bdi` tag, you add another find to get only `bdi`'s and skip its children's text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₱</span>81,495.00</bdi></span></ins>'

print(BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').find('bdi').find(string=True, recursive=False))
```

Output:

```
81,495.00
```